# Best way to design a normal map?

Tags: normals

Do people just draw them in PS and import them to blender? Or do people just model 2 of the same thing, one of higher definition? There has to be a better way. I have a model that can be tiled as a staircase, but it is very basic geometry. I want to make it more detailed but I don't know what works best.

Comment: I'd say it depends on how much detail you want in the final result. At the most I'd probably paint *very* fine details (e.g. wood grain, nicks/scratches) , but more regular things like screws, cracks between boards, etc. I'd model.

Comment: There are a number of different techniques to use to create a normal map, and in my view, which technique use in a particular situation depends upon details about the textures and software choices that are not available in the question. For example, there is a proprietary software package named [Crazy Bump](http://www.crazybump.com/) and a similar open source  called [AwesomeBump](http://awesomebump.besaba.com/). There is also at least one add-on for GIMP (gimp-normalmap-win64-1.2.3.zip) that works for normal maps.

Comment: There are at least two published video tutorials on how to create a normal map from within Blender, too. One is at <https://youtu.be/bck1eU4e8xo>; another is at <https://youtu.be/mU-cSUSR0Vs>. i'm sure there are others.

Comment: brasshat I was actually just looking at CrazyBump. Looks pretty legit, and I might get it thanks :)